# Why did the snow queen attack Marian/Zelena Specifically?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

Was there any reason behind Marian/Zelena being frozen during the Snow Queen's reign? Did she know that she was Zelena? Was she afraid of her powers? Why did she not reveal to the rest that it was her?

On the other hand, why wasn't the all powerful Zelena able to break away from the freezing curse? Or at-least somehow slow it down to make it look less powerful but without revealing that she has magical powers?

**EDIT** after other people pointed out in the comments (and I agree) is that Marian being Zelena was a plot twist they came up with later on. Let's say that the Snow Queen attacked Marian and not Zelena. What is the reasoning behind this? What reason could she possibly have to attack Marian?

Comment: I actually wonder if the writers knew she was Zelina during the first half of the season... when Regina takes out Marion's heart in 4x03 it's not darkened ... at all ... which Zelina's should be, right?

Comment: @BMWurm OMG I always had a feeling Zelena was something they added later on

Comment: @BCLC Me too, and the heart is a pretty strong clue in that regard. I think it's very likely something like Rebecca Mader becoming available for a regular spot.

Comment: @BMWurm edited with more details

Comment: Marian was the only one who never tried ice cream in her life I think?

Comment: @BMWurm 5 years later i discovered the term for this: RETCON. LAAAAAME!!!! thanks for having shared your thoughts! (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109825/why-isnt-marians-heart-darkened)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the Zelina twist was likely a later plot twist, so the curse likely wasn't intended to take out another powerful user of magic.

The primary purpose of the Snow Queen at this point was to make Elsa feel isolated, so that she will be easier to manipulate for her scheme/sisterhood development.  All the townsfolk know someone is in there town who has already frozen and attacked Storybrooke, possibly through a lack of control of their powers. Only a few who witnesses Elsa being unable to take the ice wall down know that someone else must live in the town with similar powers.  Mary Margaret "helpfully" tells the townsfolk at her meeting about Elsa, stating she is not a danger, and then in true dramatic fashion Marian freezes.  Ultimately, this should increase the distrust the townsfolk will have of Elsa.  Marian being the target was just opportunity as she happened to stop by the ice cream shop the day after Elsa showed up; the ultimate goal did not require any specific individual, just that someone was frozen and the town knew about it.

As for why Marian was picked from an out-of-story perspective, it provided ample opportunity to continue the romantic dynamic between Regina and Robin Hood without interference from Marian (rather just using her as an overarching "my wife still lives" block from Robin instead of someone who could discover the relationship flat out).  She was also a minor character and the writers weren't going to freeze someone like Emma or Killian and have them sit in ice for a couple episodes.

Comment: 'I agree that the Zelina twist was likely a later plot twist, so the curse likely wasn't intended to take out another powerful user of magic.' --> 5 years later i discovered the term for this: RETCON. LAAAAAME!!!! (of course the more lame the retcon is, the better your answer is)

Answer (score 1):

If it really was a last-minute turnaround, there would be other holes. Like Zelena's supposed death, and the fact that her "magical essence" had returned in time, back to the enchanted forest. Probably she knew about Robin's story, and saw the perfect opportunity to ruin her sister's happiness with Robin. It would be far better to see her in that unhappy state than simply having erased it from existence, in that way Regina would feel nothing, she would not suffer because she did not exist. And let's say that "Marian's" encounter with Ingrid was a fluke that worked, assuming Ingrid noticed through magic that she wasn't who she claimed to be, and to me the impressions of his face hinted at this especially when they grabbed each other's hands. So considering that Ingrid already knew her because she had been living there for a long time, she could have put a spell on the ice cream not simply to "Marian" freeze, but to somehow camouflage Zelena's dark heart. My other theory would be that this happened, on Ingrid's part, unconsciously. It would be an effect of the spell that turned favorable for the cover.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to be a comment/response to the previous answer instead of an answer to the question.  Answers need to stand on their own; please read [answer].  This might be salvageable if you [edit] it to develop your theory to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @DavidW why not convert to comment?

Comment: @BCLC Only mods can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Zelena was not all powerful.  She didn't know that Ingrid was going to put that freezing spell on her, while she was disguised as Marian.  I think you guys are trying to create a mountain out of a molehill.  Zelena (as Marian) was simply a random choice by Ingrid.  The latter could have easily chosen someone else.  For Ingrid, this was all about framing Elsa and manipulating her.

Comment: The final sentence appears to be the specific one answering the question. Could you [edit] it to expand on that a bit and add in some supporting evidence such as quotes?