# Why isn't Marian's heart darkened?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In season 4, when Regina takes out Marian's heart, it's not dark. Shouldn't it be because of the following fact?

> It is Zelena's.

Comment: Related, not dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86579/30726

Comment: presumably, the glamour spell used to disguise herself, was *extremely* effective and thorough. either that, or the writers are just making stuff up as they go along.

Comment: @phantom42 I KNEW IT!!! Post as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been no canonical answer to this given, nor has there been any interview or comment that I can find from anyone associated with the show.

In-universe, we can only speculate that Zelena's glamour spell was powerful, effective, and thorough enough to disguise her heart as well as her outward physical appearance.

Given Zelena's abilities, and the fact that Zelena knows that Regina has a penchant for ripping out people's hearts, it actually makes a good bit of sense that Zelena would make sure she was prepared just in case.

<sup>Of course, it's also entirely possible that the Marian/Zelena ruse was a late addition that the writers shoehorned in later.</sup>

Comment: 'Of course, it's also entirely possible that the Marian/Zelena ruse was a late addition that the writers shoehorned in later.' --> 5 years later i discovered the term for this: RETCON. LAAAAAME!!!! thanks phantom42! (hopefully i did say thank you before but comment was deleted for being too chatty)